# Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Invotech.Model.LoginView". No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got a problem with my project , when i am adding a controller it gives me an error which reads like this:  There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Invotech.Model.LoginView". No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Comment: Does this occur when adding an MVC controller with EF and selecting the Data Context class?

Comment: Yes Catto! I tried to check what could be the problem, even my group mates they couldn't figure out what could be the problem causing this such error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, too.  The issue was that the DbContext class had no parameterless constructor.

1. Make sure both your model class and your DbContext class have parameterless constructors
2. Compile/Build your solution before trying to create your new controller/views -- It uses the versions from the .DLL and **not** the version from the source.

Also note that while using Visual Studio's scaffolding is super-easy, it couples your business logic, database logic, and views together.  Not good separation of concerns!

Just saying.

Answer (score -1):

Add `[key]` as your primary key identifier in your table and check whether your `DataContext` is declared as the following :

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext <ApplicationUser>
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try that and see if the controller will be added succesfully.